Does there exist a function $\varphi'\in L^{\infty}(\mu)$ such that $\varphi=\varphi'$ $\mu$-a.e. and $\sigma (M_{\varphi})=\text{ran}\ (\varphi')\ $?

Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure on a measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$ and $\varphi \in L^{\infty} (\mu).$ Does there exist a function $\varphi'\in L^{\infty}(\mu)$ such that $\varphi=\varphi'$ $\mu$-a.e. and $\sigma(M_{\varphi})=\text{ran}\ \varphi'\ $? Here $M_{\varphi} \in \mathscr B (L^2 (\mu))$ is the multiplication by $\varphi.$

We know that $\sigma (M_{\varphi}) = \text{ess ran}\ \varphi.$ Hence in order to prove the desired statement we need to find a function $\varphi' \in L^{\infty} (\mu)$ such that $\varphi = \varphi'$ $\mu$-a.e. and $\text {ess ran}\ \varphi = \text {ran}\ \varphi'.$ So the above question boils down to $:$

Whether it is possible to redefine the function $\varphi$ on a measure zero set so that the range of the resultant function captures the essential range of $\varphi.$

Any suggestion in tis regard would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Not necessarily.  Consider  $\Omega$ a countable set
of atoms, each with measure $> 0$, and $\varphi$ mapping them into $[0,1]$ so that $\varphi(\Omega)$ is dense in $[0,1]$.  Then $\sigma(M_\varphi) = [0,1]$, but $\text{ran }\varphi'$ is always countable.

In this case $\varphi' = \varphi$ because the only measure zero subset of $\Omega$ is the empty set. Right?

For instance, one could have taken $\Omega = \mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$ equipped with the counting measure defined on the power set of $\Omega.$ This is a perfectly valid $\sigma$-finite measure space so that each element of $\Omega$ is an atom. Now we can simply take $\varphi$ to be the inclusion. I think this is what you meant to say in a general setting. Nice idea. Thank you sir.

@Anacardium whatever $\phi'$ you may want to take, it is a function on $\Omega$ and $\Omega$ is countable.

My point is that if $\phi'$ differs from $\phi$ on a measure zero set then $\phi' = \phi$ for otherwise if they differ at a point of $\Omega$ then each point having positive measure $\phi$ and $\phi'$ represent different class of functions in $L^2(\mu),$ a contradiction.
